# Is withTimeout() a coroutine builder? Does it block the calling thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, withtimeoutornull

1. There are three main coroutine builders launch, async, runBlocking. My question is about *withTimeout()* is it a coroutine builder?. if it is, what does it return? what is its scope? what is its dispatcher?
2. I have following piece of code:

   ```
   val myScope =  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

   runBlocking{

      myScope.launch {  //coroutine#1
        Log.i(TAG, "First coroutine launched")
      }

      withTimeout(3000){
        delay(2000)
        Log.i(TAG, "withTimeout block executed")
      }

      myScope.launch { //coroutine#2
         Log.i(TAG, "Second coroutine launched")
      }

   }
   ```

The output is:

```
First coroutine launched
withTimeout block executed
Second coroutine launched
```

Here you can see *withTimeout* takes two seconds to complete the task but still coroutine#2 executed after this block. It means that *withTimeout* blocks the calling thread.
If it does not block the calling thread then output should be like this:

```
First coroutine launched
Second coroutine launched
withTimeout block executed
```

Am I right? please help me in understanding this scenario. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`withTimeout()` is a `suspend` function so it should be invoked from a coroutine or another `suspend` function.

**Coroutine builder** is a bridge from the normal to the suspending world.

> There are three main coroutine builders launch, async, runBlocking. My question is about withTimeout() is it a coroutine builder?. if it is, what does it return? what is its scope? what is its dispatcher?

According to the docs: "Runs a given suspending block of code inside a coroutine ...", I've used logs to check, and it appears that it uses the current coroutine to execute the block of code, but it also waits for it to finish. `withTimeout()` is not a coroutine builder, because it is a `suspend` function by itself and it's not a bridge from the normal to the suspending world.
It returns whatever the `block`, passed as the last parameter, returns. It creates another scope (`TimeoutCoroutine`) and uses it as a receiver. It uses the current context's `CoroutineDispatcher`.

> It means that withTimeout blocks the calling thread

`withTimeout()` is a `suspend` function, it doesn't block the thread, but suspends the coroutine it is launched in until the `block` is finished execution, or timeout fires. If `block` executes longer than provided timeout, then an exception will be thrown and `coroutine#2` will not be executed.

Comment: 1. **it doesn't block the thread, but suspends the coroutine it is launched in until the block is finished execution** it means that code/coroutines after withTimeout will execute only after this block completed its execution. In the above example coroutine#2 will execute after withTimeout.                                                                           2. In the above example withTimeout will execute its code in runBlocking coroutine               
        Am I right?

Comment: **it might create another coroutine to execute block of code.**  if it creates a new coroutine then we can say it is a coroutine builder. Now question is, what are the contextual elements (Dispatcher, scope, job etc.) of this coroutine?  Thank you for your support

Comment: I've just tested it with some logs, and it appears that it works in the same coroutine as `runBlocking`, but uses different scope.